# Zend_Db_Table_Abstract - update?

Tags: zend-framework

we have this on Zend Manual:

```
$table = new Bugs();

      $data = array(
       'updated_on'      => '2007-03-23',
       'bug_status'      => 'FIXED'
      );
$where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('bug_id = ?', 1234);
$table->update($data, $where);
```

Why do we need getAdapter and quoteInto again? I've read the manual but I don't understand.

What about the save() method, shouldn't we use it instead?

Regards,
MEM

Answer (score 0):

save() is for when you are using `Zend_Db_Table_Row` if you are using Zend_Db_Table only, update is the method.

The code you've pasted needs to have the getAdapter and quoteInfo because $table is an instance of Bugs but not necessarily Zend_Db_Table_Row or Zend_Db_Table, therefore it isn't connected to the db.